# PostgreSQL - Variables on transaction-level

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Do PostgreSQL have variables at transaction level? If not, is it possible to implement something like that relatively easily? Unfortunately, I am still relatively inexperienced with PostgreSQL and have **only found out that you can define settings at session level.**

I am currently trying to implement a historization like Hibernate has directly in PostgreSQL. A short info for which they do not know Hibernate: Hibernate has a table for revisions.  It contains an ID, the time and other information. For each table there is a "_AUD" table. Every change within the same transaction gets the same revision ID.

To implement this directly in PostgreSQL, **I would need a variable that I can use within a transaction and whose value can only be used within the same transaction**. My idea is that every time a transaction is historized, a function queries if an ID exists for the transaction, if not, it creates one, otherwise it returns the already created one.

**I use the latest PostgreSQL version.**

Comment: "*Every change within the same transaction gets the same revision ID*" - what about using Postgres' internal transaction ID for that? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Omg... you're right. I was so fixated on settings/variables, I never even thought about it. Thank you! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: be aware that transaction IDs do get recycled eventually, so if you want it to be permanently unique include a timestamp like `now()` (which also has a fixed value for the duration of the transaction)

Comment: @Jasen "The internal transaction ID type (xid) is 32 bits wide and wraps around every 4 billion transactions. However, these functions export a 64-bit format that is extended with an “epoch” counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation. " - Doesn't that guarantee uniqueness within an installation? I already have a timestamp in it, but putting it in the primary key wouldn't make this thing any faster.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From today's point of view it was rather a stupid idea or bad design and I would pass this parameter directly to the database.